# ¿Es correcto escribir un punto antes de empezar una explicación?

Tags: puntuación

Estaba leyendo [una noticia](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2017/02/14/actualidad/1487078682_473794.html) cuando di con el siguiente párrafo:

> La situación deportiva de Roman Zozulya podría resolverse en los próximos días. Todo depende de las gestiones que el entorno del futbolista está realizando para encontrar acomodo al delantero en su país, en concreto en el Dnipro. **El caso del jugador, algo enrevesado, está de la siguiente forma.** Después de múltiples indagaciones, la FIFA ha dado su consentimiento para (...). El máximo organismo internacional ha realizado (...)

Como veis, tras unas líneas introductorias, el periodista procede a detenerse para dar paso a una explicación. Esto yo lo habría fijado con dos puntos:

> (...) El caso está de la siguiente **forma: después** de múltiples indagaciones...

Sin embargo, veo la complejidad del asunto (gramatical, pues el futbolístico lo dejo aparte). En efecto, se trata de una explicación larga que necesita de distintas frases.

Es como si dijéramos:

> A mí me gustan los fines de **semana:**<sub>dos puntos</sub> voy a patinar, pero también disfruto de dormir mucho. Además, siempre intento ver películas.

El ámbito de acción de los dos puntos parece lo que viene inmediatamente después y hasta el punto, por lo que entiendo que escribir lo siguiente (de acuerdo con la técnica del periodista) podría tener sentido:

> A mí me gustan los fines de **semana.**<sub>punto y seguido</sub> Voy a patinar, pero también disfruto de dormir mucho. Además, siempre intento ver películas.

¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿Hay alguna regla al respecto? ¿Aplican los dos puntos a solamente lo indicado en el texto inmediatamente después de los dos puntos y hasta el primer punto?

Comment: Al igual que tú, yo no los usaría, pondría dos puntos, acto seguido, inicio la explicación. No estoy seguro sí sea correcto, pero en mi opinión diría que está mal redactado dado que el punto lo tomo como el fin de una sentencia y el inicio de una nueva, que puede estar o no relacionada, ahí ya depende del contexto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que sí es correcto. En la *Ortografía 2010*, en [el epígrafe sobre los dos puntos](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KMzDTFipKxfqUNmY), podemos leer por un lado que

> Los dos puntos completan el grupo de signos genuinamente delimitadores, en el que figuran también el punto, la coma y el punto y coma. Como los dos últimos, el signo de los dos puntos delimita unidades sintácticas inferiores al enunciado, oracionales o no.

Es decir, que dada la jerarquía de signos de puntuación, los dos puntos están por debajo del punto, y por tanto lo que presentan no debería ir más allá del siguiente punto y seguido (salvo que lo que se presente sea un discurso citado, que en tu caso no lo es).

Más aún:

> Dado su valor anunciativo, los dos puntos aparecen en contextos bastante bien delimitados [...].

Tampoco es el caso de tu ejemplo, donde el texto que expone el caso del jugador no está claramente delimitado, sino que puede ser una redacción que se extienda durante varios párrafos.

Si la frase fuera así:

> El caso del jugador [...] se expone a continuación.

a lo mejor de esta forma el punto no chirriaría tanto.

Comment: ¡Se me fue la pinza y no comenté por aquí! Interesante, así pues podemos ver los dos puntos como un "abridor de contexto" que abarca hasta hasta el siguiente punto. Probablemente lo apropiado es poner dos puntos y luego una lista de elementos, pero no parece un formato adecuado para un artículo periodístico.